# Delete Query inside Where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Is there any possibility to write delete query inside **Where clause**.

Example:

```
Select ID,Name From MyTable Where ID IN(Delete From MyTable)
```

It may be crazy, but let me explain my situation. In our reporting tool, we are supporting to enter SQL where query.
We will use our own **Select** and **From** **Clause** query and combine the user's where query input.

Example:

```
Select ID,Name From MyTable Where ("Query typed by user")
```

Here, user can type any kind of where query filter..

If he types like **ID=100** our final query becomes like this

```
Select ID,Name From MyTable Where (ID=100)
```

One of our customer asked us what will happen if anyone type the delete query as where query filter. he feels this may be the security hole..so we have tried that kind of possibility in our dev environment. But the sql returns error for the following query.

```
Select ID,Name From MyTable Where ID IN(Delete From MyTable)
```

So finally, my question is, is there any other possibility to write **Delete Query** inside **Where clause** or **Select clause**.. If it possible, how can I restrict it?

Comment: YES!  If they enter their query as something like ";GO;DELETE FROM MyTable".  There are many variations on this so you really need to look into ways to stop SQL injection.  The simplest way to avoid this is to parameterise your query and pass the user text as a parameter.

Comment: Yes this is very dangerous. They could put something like 1=1; delete from table. Lookup sql injection.

Comment: This is SQL Injection, and you shouldn't let a user type any kind of query s/he wants. What if the query they add is `ID=100); DELETE FROM MyTable;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  They can run a delete.  They can type:

```
 1 = 1; DELETE FROM MY_TABLE;
```

Or even worse in some ways, (since you should have backups):

```
1 = 0 UNION SELECT SOCIAL_SECURITY_NUMBER, CREDIT_CARD_NUMBER, OTHER_SENSITIVE_DATA FROM MY_SENSITIVE_TABLE;
```

Now, in your case its hard to validate.  Normally if you are just passing a value to filter on you can use parameterised sql to save yourself.  You however also need to let the user select a column.  In cases like these, usually we use a drop down to allow the user to select a predefined list of columns and then validate the column name server side.  We give the user a text box to enter the value to match and then parameterise that.

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite possible. But he can do something like this :

```
Select ID,Name From MyTable Where (ID=100); (DELETE FROM MyTable Where 1 = 1)
```

by using `ID=100); (DELETE FROM MyTable Where 1 = 1` instead of `ID=100`

Answer (score 0):

I believe what your customer is talking about is SQL injection, as long as you have taken appropriate methods to block other queries from running after your select statement is done, then you should have no problem in letting them type whatever it is that you want.
From my experience there is no way to delete anything when you are doing a select statement.
Just make sure you have query terminator characters so they don't write something like the following.

```
select column1,column2, from myTable where ID in (1,2); delete from my table
```

this would be a valid worry from your customer if you aren't taking proper steps to prevent sql injection from happening.

You could have your SQL reporting tool just not have update, or delete permission and just have it have Read permission. However, it is up to you guys have you handle your sql injection security.